# Is it a Python bug that the main thread of a process created in a daemon thread is a daemon itself?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, fork

When I call `os.fork()` inside a daemon thread, the main thread in the child process has the `daemon` property set to `True`. This is very confusing, since the program keeps running while the only thread is a daemon. According to the docs, if all the threads are daemons the program should exit.

Here is an example:

```
import os
import threading


def child():
     assert not threading.current_thread().daemon  # This shouldn't fail


def parent():
    new_pid = os.fork()
    if new_pid == 0:
        child()
    else:
        os.waitpid(new_pid, 0)


t = threading.Thread(target=parent)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
t.join()
```

Is it a bug in the CPython implementation?

Comment: Am I right in correcting your question?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that the daemonization is only relevant for threads *other* than the main-thread. In the main-thread, the return-value of `current_thread().daemon` is hard-coded to be `False`.

See the relevant source code here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/threading.py#L1097

So after a fork, there is only one thread, and it's consequently the main-thread.

Which means it can never be a daemon-thread.

I can not point you to any documentation beyond the source, but it is most certainly *not* a bug - it would be a bug the other way round, if your expectation was met.

The interaction between fork and threads are complex, and as I mentioned: don't mix them before fork.

Comment: Could you point to the official Python docs, that say this is the expected behavior? IMO the docs are clear: if all the threads are daemons, the process terminates. This simply doesn't happen.

Answer (score -1):

> This is very confusing, since the program keeps running while the only thread is a daemon. According to the docs, if all the threads are daemons the program should exit.

You are explicitly waiting for the thread to end. Whether the thread is a daemon or not has no effect to `t.join()`. The thread again won't end unless the child process has terminated due to `os.waitpid()`.

I'm not sure about the behaviour of a forked thread, though, so I can't tell you why you experience what you do.

Comment: The question is about the daemon status of the main thread of the child process, not about the parent process.